# Memory error using multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a server that has to process a lot of image, so i have a function that creates a process for every image:

```
def create_models(files_path, models_path, num_model_photos, uid):
"""
:param uid:
:param files_path:
:param models_path:
:param num_model_photos:
:return:
"""

# start a process for every img
i = 1
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(files_path, '*')):

    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=create_single_model,args=[filename, models_path, num_model_photos, uid, i])
    process.start()

    print(f'Process: {i}')
    i = i + 1
```

In create_single_model i perform the operations on the image (and some other operations with database):

```
def create_single_model(filename, models_path, num_model_photos, uid,i):
original_name = os.path.basename(filename).split(".", 1)  # takes file's name removing the extension type
img = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
mask, orientations = morpho_otsu(filename)  # computes mask and orientation from the image file
name_with_orientation = orientations + "_" + original_name[0]  
save_masked_image(models_path, name_with_orientation, img, mask)
```

Well, i realized that with more then 25 images (so more than 25 processes) it crashes and give me a lot of errors like theese:

```
File "C:\Users\Francesco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 1455] Il file di paging è troppo piccolo per essere completato

 File "D:\ProgrammiPython\Predictive-Emoji-Keyboards\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\lapack.py", line 664, in <module>
from scipy.linalg import _flapack
 ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _flapack: Il file di paging è troppo piccolo per essere completato

 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 973, in get_data
 MemoryError
```

Comment: you dont have enough RAM for what you're trying to do..you need to refactor

Comment: Do you mean i need to reduce memory accesses in my functions? it's not possible to perform a short term solution like deallocate memory or start the next process when i got enough memory?

Comment: I mean you have to find a way to store less data in RAM at a given time, otherwise you'll max out your RAM. I don't have a solution for you, but you need to find a spot in your code where you can purge data from RAM before the next operation or find another method which does the s9me thing and stores less IN RAM

Comment: @DerekEden how do you purge the RAM in a Python code? Are there some guidelines in this respect?

Comment: just delete variables that are taking up alot of space